# TypeScript error setting a variable: "Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts"

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am not so into TypeScript and I have the following doubt with this code.
The code is obtained from a Udemy tutorial but it give me an error. I suppose that the proble could be something related to new TypeScript version or something like this.

I am working on an Angular project using Angular Material and I have this component class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  maxDate: Date;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    maxDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getFullYear() - 18);
  }

  onSubmit(form:NgForm) {
    console.log(form);

  }

}
```

The IDE and the compiler give me an error on this line:

```
maxDate: Date;
```

The error is:

```
Property 'maxDate' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
```

Basically in the example it is declaring this variable as class field and than it is setting the value into the **ngOnInit()** method. It seems pretty straightforward but I am obtaining this error.

Why this error? What changed? How can I try to fix it?

Comment: You also have a typo, it should be `this.maxDate = new Date();`

Comment: "What changed"? - Angular introduced more strict setting and uses TypeScript's strict mode, see https://blog.angular.io/angular-cli-strict-mode-c94ba5965f63

Answer (score 0):

First add you are missing `this.` in your `ngOnInit`.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.maxDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getFullYear() - 18);
  }
```

if the problem still occurs try:

```
constructor() {
this.maxDate = new Date();
 }
```

or initialize the variable when you declare it:

```
maxDate = new Date();
```

the explanation to the error is because you are using `typescript`, it makes sure all your variables has been initialize you can turn this off by
adding this on your ts configuration file.

```
"strictPropertyInitialization": false
```

this way you can create global variable without initialize them.

or if you want to leave it you can also:

```
maxDate!:Date;
```

Comment: It's also possible to set a value on declaration, this should be mentioned as well